# Configuring number of idle instances on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to set my app to always have a few instances idle.

Here's an extract of my app.yaml:

```
version: 3
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 5
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: app.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Some info: **the app is paid**, has **several modules** - all running with **default settings**.

For this particular module (default), I'd like to set up idle instances and have added the relevant code into app.yaml (which is the yaml config for the default instance).

What happens currently is that the **app is uploaded successfully** (suggesting no syntax errors in yaml) - but **no change is to be seen in the admin console**.

Any idea why?

Source of config: [AppEngine Python Modules Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/)

Comment: what changes do you expect in admin console?

Comment: You'll have to add 'module: default' to use those settings.

Comment: @marcadian I expect to see 5 instances with the label "resident" or "idle" under "Instances". Currently there is a variable number of instances (normally 1 - or 0 when there is no traffic), always labelled "dynamic"

Comment: @Mario thanks, will give this a try now.

Comment: @Mario, I have added the line and it gets read in without any errors. However, still no resident instances activated...

Comment: Something that surprises me is that the app.yaml gets accepted. When you have modules, App Engine wants you to put the version name in text, like three instead of 3. Are you sure it's getting fed this app.yaml? and have you checked your default version has been updated? Could you share your app id with Bruyere and me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging and testing I have an explanation. (For future readers this does NOT apply to Java) When you set the minimum number of instances in python it doesn't spool up the instances. The reason for this is Python start up times are very fast normally. Once the instances are called though it won't kill them unless its above your minimum. EX:

You set minimum idle instances to 5. There is little traffic so only one is spawned. It will stay at 1. Now all of a sudden your site gets Facebook-ed and you get enough traffic for 3 instances it will spawn the 2 new ones. When the traffic dies down those 3 will stay alive indefinitely. Now your site gets tweeted and your traffic needs 10 spawns up to keep up with requests. When people go to bed your app will be scaled back to you minimum instances and stay there.

Comment: This may explain a lot! Thanks @Bruyere, will try this on my side :D

Comment: I think this explains that: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_states